# Preventing merge conflicts with a `black` formatted local branch and non-formatted upstream branch

Tags: python, git, github, version-control, formatting

There is a Python package that I have cloned. I've set the parent Python package to be the upstream branch so that I can keep my version up-to-date with any changes to the parent code. However, I'd like to keep my version formatted with `isort` and `black`, whereas the original code has no formatting whatsoever.

Is there some magical way for me to `git fetch upstream` and then `git merge upstream/main` in this scenario without getting merge conflicts? For instance, is there a way to run `black` between these steps?